# What categorical concept do the `fmap_i` mappings (implied by an applicative) formed?

Tags: category-theory, computer-science

According to  *Programming in Haskell* by Hutton, in Haskell,   class `Functor` is declared as:

```
class   Functor f   where
fmap    ::  (a  ->  b)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b
```

Is it correct that `f` and `fmap` form an endofunctor on the category of types?

Class `Applicative` is declared as:

> ```
> class Functor f   =>  Applicative f   where
> pure  ::  a   ->  f   a
> (<*>) ::  f   (a  ->  b)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b
> ```

which provides:

> ```
> fmap0 ::  a   ->  f   a
> fmap0 =   pure
> fmap1 ::  (a  ->  b)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b
> fmap1 g   x   =   pure    g   <*> x
> fmap2 ::  (a  ->  b   ->  c)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b   ->  f   c
> fmap2 g   x   y   =   pure    g   <*> x   <*> y
> fmap3 ::  (a  ->  b   ->  c   ->  d)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b   ->  f   c   ->  f   d
> fmap3 g   x   y   z   =   pure    g   <*> x   <*> y   <*> z
> ```

Is it correct that `fmap0` and `fmap1` form an endofunctor on the category of types?

Do `fmap0`, `fmap1`, and `fmap2` form an endofunctor too? If not, what categorical concept do they form?

Similar questions for `fmap0`, `fmap1`, `fmap2`, and `fmap3`, and for more.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "form an endofunctor on the category of types"? An endofunctor is always _two_ maps, one for objects, and one for morphisms. In that sense, the answer is clearly "no", because you only give a single map in each instance.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes and no.

When you declare a `Functor`, you're promising the users of your code that composition and identity are preserved by the functor, but Haskell's type checker doesn't check that for you.

Likewise, when you declare an `Applicative`, you're promising users that the axioms for a [lax monoidal functor with strength](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12412/explaining-applicative-functor-in-categorical-terms-monoidal-functors) are satisfied. But again, this isn't verified by the type checker.

Newer languages in the ML family (Agda or Idris, say) can exhibit "verified" versions of `Functor` and `Applicative`, which require the programmer to provide proofs that the axioms are satisfied along with the definitions.

Comment: Thanks. `fmap_i, i >= 1` are mappings between morphisms.  `fmap_0` seems to be a morphism, and can it be considered as a mapping between morphisms?